# Does the spin rate of a black hole correspond to a physical feature?

Tags: black-hole

If the mass and orbital period for two neutron stars is known before collapse to a black hole and the rate of spin is known after collapse, 100 revolutions per second for instance, that will correlate mathmatically to a specific radius.

Does this radius correlate to a physical feature of the black hole such as a surface? Does this radius fall between the radius of the physical substance and the Schwarzschild radius? Is it the largest, intermediate, or the smallest of these?

Comment: Black holes are characterised by an angular momentum, not an angular velocity (which is unknown/undefined).

Comment: A black hole doesn't *have* a physical surface, but it has one or more horizons. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotating_black_hole

Comment: @RobJeffries There *is* an angular velocity associated to a black hole $\omega_{H} =\frac{a}{2M r_{+}}$, which is often interpreted as the angular velocity of the horizon. Specifying $M$ and $\omega_H$ is of course full equivalent to specifying $M$ and $J$ or $M$ and $a$